# How to stop grafana from converting hex-string to integer?

Tags: sql, hex, grafana, clickhouse

I have grafana running with its datasource as clickhouse which has a column which stores hex-representations as string. Grafana is automatically conerting the hex value to decimal which I do not want to happen. How do I stop grafana from converting the data ?

Comment: Did you solve the issue? I have the same problem

Answer (score 2):

I've experienced this with other data sources in Grafana (e.g. PostgreSQL and Prometheus) and what I did might help someone.

The general idea is to display the hexadecimal values as **Strings**. For that, navigate to:
`Panel editor (right) > Standard options > Unit > Misc`
and choose **String** (see image below).

[image]

Other relevant details:

- **Grafana version:** v8.2.6
- **Panel type:** Table

Comment: This worked for me, for an Elastic data source, which returned strings containing integers like `001526`, which I wanted to display as is.

Answer (score 0):

could you click "query inspector" in grafana and share a screenshot with `data` section with returned values?

maybe wrong behavior is here
https://github.com/Vertamedia/clickhouse-grafana/blob/5a33946dfa2d3dc1d678f2c8e90d72e34ad701cb/src/sql_series.ts#L207

I think you can use something like this as a quick workaround:

```
SELECT concat("_",your_field) AS string_field ...
```

feel free to open a new issue with steps to reproduce on https://github.com/Vertamedia/clickhouse-grafana/issues/